# How can I get the count of name grater than 2 from file using Python programming?

Tags: python

**I have a file with id,name,sal. what is the code for it in python to get the name of the employees whose name is repeated two or more than two times?**

example data:

```
101,Ramu,2000
102,Mahesh,3000
103,Anni,4000
104,Ramu,4000
105,Laxmi,5000
106,Mahesh,6000
107,Ramu,7000
```

Output should be:

```
101,Ramu,2000
104,Ramu,4000
107,Ramu,7000
106,Mahesh,6000
102,Mahesh,3000
```

Can you help me on it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We are not a coding service. Although beginners are really welcome, we do expect a certain degree of effort on your part. If you want to have a chance to receive an answer, you have to research on your side, show us what you have tried to achieve your requirements and ask a specific question about a particular problem in your code that you want to solve. As is, your question is too broad and [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to count the number of occurrences per name in one loop.
Then print accordingly in a second loop.

```
data = [
    '101,Ramu,2000',
    '102,Mahesh,3000',
    '103,Anni,4000',
    '104,Ramu,4000',
    '105,Laxmi,5000',
    '106,Mahesh,6000',
    '107,Ramu,7000',
]

counts = {}
for row in data:
    name = row.split(',')[1]

    if name in counts:
        counts[name] += 1
    else:
        counts[name] = 1

for row in data:
    name = row.split(',')[1]

    if counts[name] >= 2:
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
101,Ramu,2000
102,Mahesh,3000
104,Ramu,4000
106,Mahesh,6000
107,Ramu,7000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the solution.